# error when using single quotes in mysql when creating a database

Tags: mysql

I want to create a database that has a dash in the name, like my-db. i have tried

```
create database 'my-db';
```

Below is the output from my terminal

mysql> CREATE DATABASE 'my-db';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''my-db'' at line 1

I have googled how to create such a database name and all links tell me to use single quotes around the name. But i don't know why its not working for me. How else can i create database with name that has a dash in it?

Comment: Use backticks - not single quotes - for names. Single quotes are for text strings.

Comment: "The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”) ...  If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks" [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: Joachim Isaksson thanks. I saw the the backticks on the pages i was getting from google, looked for it on my keyboard and didn't find it. So i guested was suppose to be single quotes. I only had to look a little closer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
create database `my-db`;
```

or

```
create database my-db;
```

It must work.

For database you should use backticks or not use any symbols.

Comment: the first one works, but the second does not. Output mysql> create database my-db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db' at line 1

Comment: Oh. Of course. Usually it works when used only letters and numbers in database name. Use `-` is non-standartd